# Storing Time_Select in Array Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looping through an array of weekdays (sun-mon). I would like to save a time for each day in a separate array called `delivery_times`:

views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
  <% Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index do |day, index| %>
      <div class="field">
          <%= day %><br>
          <%= check_box_tag "delivery_days[]", index %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :time %><br>
          <%= f.time_select :time, "delivery_times[]" => :time %>
      </div>   
  <% end %>
```

Controller

```
  def create
    @times = params[:delivery_times]
    params[:delivery_days].each do |day, time|
      @order = Order.create(order_params.merge( {:day => day}, {:time => @times[index]} ))
    end
      redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.'
  end
```

Currently `delivery_days` is saved correctly, but `delivery_times` does not save the times. I tried finding `time_select_tag`, but it does not exist. How can I store the time into the array?

Comment: Do you mean it's not saved to database? Are you using rails 4? Can you show us the relevant code in your controller? Maybe the attribute is not permitted there.

Comment: @panmari Just added the controller. `params[:delivery_times]` is not returning an array with data. And yes, using rails 4

Comment: Can you show us from the rails console, what the params are that reach your server? Also it would be interesting to see the method `order_params` from the bottom of your controller (google strong parameters in rails if you're unsure what this method does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ActionView` `time_tag`, [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_tag)

```
<%= f.time_field :time, "delivery_times" => :time %>
```

Comment: I tried that. I get this error: `undefined method `time' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f817141a498>`

Comment: But `time_field` does not allow user to select a time. I'd like a user to select a time (not input custom time)